# Using levenshtein distance in knn regression model

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, bioinformatics, levenshtein-distance

I am interested in predicting the stability of my proteins using a KNN regression model, however I would like to use instead of the sequences themselves, the levenshtein distances calculated as the embedding of my proteins as the input variables for my model. I wish to measure the nonconformity of each instance using the training errors of k nearest neighbors depending on the levenshtein distances per sequence.

I do not wish to one hot encode them if possible.

My input table looks like this:

```
new_host  sequence    expression
FALSE     AQVPYGVS-   0.039267878
FALSE     ASVPYGVSI   0.039267878
FALSE     STNL-GSGR   0.261456561
FALSE     NLYGSGL-R   0.265188519
FALSE     SLGP-NLYG   0.419680588
FALSE     A-SLGTTNG   0.145710993
```

For my output, I'm not sure if I can actually get a particular distance for each and if this would be used for the input of my KNN regression model.

My function to calculate the levenshtein distance:

```
def levenshtein(seq1, seq2):
    size_x = len(seq1) + 1
    size_y = len(seq2) + 1
    matrix = np.zeros ((size_x, size_y))
    for x in range(size_x):
        matrix [x, 0] = x
    for y in range(size_y):
        matrix [0, y] = y

    for x in range(1, size_x):
        for y in range(1, size_y):
            if seq1[x-1] == seq2[y-1]:
                matrix [x,y] = min(
                    matrix[x-1, y] + 1,
                    matrix[x-1, y-1],
                    matrix[x, y-1] + 1
                )
            else:
                matrix [x,y] = min(
                    matrix[x-1,y] + 1,
                    matrix[x-1,y-1] + 1,
                    matrix[x,y-1] + 1
                )
    print (matrix)
    return (matrix[size_x - 1, size_y - 1])
```

My function to calculate the nonconformity of each instance:

```
  def nonconformity(self, z, Z):
        """Return k-Nearest Neighbours (kNN) nonconformity measure.
        
        Parameters
        ----------
        z : array-like, shape (n_features,)
            Test vector, where n_features is the number of features.
        Z : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_features)
            Training vectors, where n_samples is the number of samples,
            n_features is the number of features.
        Returns
        -------
        r : float
            kNN nonconformity measure on z with respect to Z.
        """
        # Take the k smallest distances between z rows and zn and sum them.
        dist = cdist(Z, [z])[:,0]
        r = np.sort(dist)[:self.k].sum()
    
        return r
```

Desired Output (Not sure if this is even possible)

```
new_host  sequence    expression   Levenshtein Distance
FALSE     AQVPYGVS-   0.039267878    0
FALSE     ASVPYGVSI   0.039267878    0.1
FALSE     STNL-GSGR   0.261456561    0.2 
FALSE     NLYGSGL-R   0.265188519    0.2 
FALSE     SLGP-NLYG   0.419680588    0.4
FALSE     A-SLGTTNG   0.145710993    0.5
```

Comment: cross-posted: https://www.biostars.org/p/450586/

Comment: @Pierre as mentioned i removed from the previous forum, thought this would not be an issue asI considered them to be completely two different forums.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you need to find the distance of each string with all strings. But doing this approach will fail as if the length of sequences be `n` and sequence length be `m` then O`(n*n*m*m)` complexity. You can try using a dummy string(like origin: `"---------"`) to calculate Levenshtein distances for all the sequences.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sequence = ["AQVPYGVS-", "ASVPYGVSI", "STNL-GSGR", "NLYGSGL-R", "SLGP-NLYG", "A-SLGTTNG"]   
expression = [0.039267878, 0.039267878, 0.145710993, 0.419680588, 0.265188519, 0.261456561]

def levenshtein(seq1, seq2):
    size_x = len(seq1) + 1
    size_y = len(seq2) + 1
    matrix = np.zeros ((size_x, size_y))
    for x in range(size_x):
        matrix [x, 0] = x
    for y in range(size_y):
        matrix [0, y] = y

    for x in range(1, size_x):
        for y in range(1, size_y):
            if seq1[x-1] == seq2[y-1]:
                matrix [x,y] = min(
                    matrix[x-1, y] + 1,
                    matrix[x-1, y-1],
                    matrix[x, y-1] + 1
                )
            else:
                matrix [x,y] = min(
                    matrix[x-1,y] + 1,
                    matrix[x-1,y-1] + 1,
                    matrix[x,y-1] + 1
                )
    # print (matrix)
    return (matrix[size_x - 1, size_y - 1])


seq_distances = np.empty((0, len(sequence)), int)
for seq1 in range(0, len(sequence)):
    seq1_dist = []
    for seq2 in range(0, len(sequence)):
        seq1_dist.append(levenshtein(sequence[seq1], sequence[seq2]))    
    seq_distances = np.vstack((seq_distances, np.array(seq1_dist)))

print(seq_distances)

# Something of this sort can be used.
dist = distance.cdist(seq_distances, [seq_distances[0]])
r = np.sort(dist, axis=0)[:k].sum()
```

Output:

```
[[0. 2. 8. 8. 8. 8.]
 [2. 0. 8. 8. 8. 8.]
 [8. 8. 0. 5. 7. 8.]
 [8. 8. 5. 0. 7. 9.]
 [8. 8. 7. 7. 0. 6.]
 [8. 8. 8. 9. 6. 0.]]
```

Comment: hey! Thanks for following up, basically I was curious if I could even get an output as mentioned above, this is great though. Please look at my new question.

Comment: See the above you mentioned can only be done if you calculate each sequence distance from a dummy sequence, for my answer you need two columns `seq_1` and `seq_2` as they are the matrix indices and give their Levenshtein distance. You can flatten the matrix and get the desired results.